# how to fix the position of a div

Tags: css

In my webpage a division should be in a fixed position at the left side of the page. As per my knowledge i have used

`position:fixed;top:100px;left:20px;`. By using this code i got the exact position where i want. but When i am scrolling down the page that division is at the same position and at top of that division i am getting the 100px space as because i have give `top:100px` . But i dont want that space. Please help me.

Thanks in advance,
Sree ram

Comment: try `position:absolute;` instead of `fixed`

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want the thing to stay in the *exact* position, regardless of the current viewport but instead in relation to the document as a whole, then you want an *absolute* position, not a *fixed* one:

```
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:20px;
```

Comment: No actually if i use `absolute` when i scroll down the page it will not visible. But what i am saying is that when the page is loaded the division should be from `top:100px`, when we scroll down the page it should become top:0px and it should be fixed there.

Comment: @user2281995 Then you're asking two completely different things, you want to dynamically change the style of an element based on the current scroll state, which isn't something you can do with pure CSS, you'll need to set the initial style, then, using JavaScript, detect when scrolling, and when scrolled to 100px or greater, change the applied style to specify 0px for top.

Answer (score 2):

So as to fix the position of a div, 
you must apply the absolute position.

It makes the div stay in the particular position no matter what.

The code shall be:

```
position : absolute;
top : 100px;
left : 20px;
```

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a better view on various css positions from [CSS POSITIONS REFERENCE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Now please try making following changes

```
position : absolute;
top : 100px;
left : 20px;
```